# Does the import script of "Stream Firestore to BigQuery" run on multi threads when triggered from Firebase console?

Tags: firebase, firebase-extensions

For running the import script of [Stream Firestore to BigQuery](https://extensions.dev/extensions/firebase/firestore-bigquery-export), we have two options.

A. Run `npx @firebaseextensions/fs-bq-import-collection` ([ref](https://github.com/firebase/extensions/blob/master/firestore-bigquery-export/guides/IMPORT_EXISTING_DOCUMENTS.md))

B. Answer "Yes" to the question "Import existing Firestore documents into BigQuery?" when you install the extension.

With the option A, I can choose if I run the script on multi threads, while I cannot with the option B.

Does the import script run on multi threads or a single thread when I go with the option B?

I couldn't find any information related to the question on the [README.md](https://github.com/firebase/extensions/tree/master/firestore-bigquery-export).

Comment: Why don't read what the [source code](https://github.com/firebase/extensions/blob/master/firestore-bigquery-export/scripts/import/src/index.ts) is doing?